# regex extract number from multiline result

Tags: regex

I have a log result that looks like this:

```
  115ms: http-534i/rBbJ: Foo.collection1.find({"_id": $ObjectId, "parentId": null})
  32ms: http-M5odfO/rsfv: Foo.collection2.find({"someField": $String})
  22ms: http-pdKCo/zuAx: Foo.collection3.find({"_id": $ObjectId})
```

I'd like to search on 'someField' and extract 32 from the line.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a basic regex to match and capture those digits.

```
(\d+).*someField
```

I would possbily use a word boundary.

```
(\d+).*\bsomeField
```